# starting application with speed detection

Tags: java, android, gps, detect

I am looking for a way to start my application automatically as soon as the users phone GPS detects certain speed, is it even possible to do such thing?
I have been looking for a while for that in google without much success.

Comment: no need to add the android studio tag to this, android studio is just an IDE

Answer (score 0):

> is it even possible to do such thing?

No.

The closest thing would be to have your app running 24 hours a day, constantly checking GPS and then taking specific action when the speed reaches your desired level. This will be exceptionally bad for the battery and has significant privacy implications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact use case is, but maybe Google's Awareness API maybe of use to you, look it up here https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview